# Is System.currentTimeMillis() the best measure of time performance in Java?

Tags: java, performance, big-o

Is System.currentTimeMillis() the best measure of time performance in Java? Are there any gotcha's when using this to compare the time before action is taken to the time after the action is taken? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458267/741970

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope not - it's what I use when i don't use [`nanoTime()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).

Comment: One gotcha (on Windows w. Sun JDK6, in any case) with `nanoTime` is that the value returned depends on the CPU core executing the thread. If the thread starts executing on one core and finishes on another core, your numbers will be somewhat off. I had code like `long start = System.nanoTime(); doIt(); long elapsedNanos = System.nanoTime() - start;` and wound up with `elapsedNanos` being negative.

Comment: if between start and end time the Thread got suspended then end time will actually reflect the suspend time as well. so the end-start will not be the actual time Thread spent in execution.

Answer (score 2):

besides `System.nanoTime()`, JMX is probably the best viable option:

```
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()
```

you can query current thread cpu time (measured in nano seconds but not with nano seconds precision, as for `System.nanoTime`())

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Stopwatch from Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) which makes measuring time super-easy.

Comment: Why guava stopwatch is better than System.currentTimeMillis()?

Answer (score 1):

If you need monotonic time measurements, System.nanoTime is a better choice. System.currentTimeMillis is subject to UTC timing variations -- leap seconds, NTP updates and jitter, as well as users setting the system clock*. This can cause some spectacular failures in certain kinds of timing applications. System.nanoTime is supposed to be immune to all that.

The problems with System.nanoTime include periodic numeric overflow and long term timing inaccuracy, making System.currentTimeMillis better for longer time spans (provided that users leave the system clock alone). Note that daylight saving time and time zone changes should not affect System.currentTimeMillis.

*Windows "Sync with internet time" makes stepwise changes. This can be very disruptive, as opposed to a proper NTP client implementation that "chases" the server by adjusting the client timebase frequency.

Comment: The nearest "periodic numeric overflow" of `nanoTime` will happen `2262-04-11 23:47:16 UTC+0`

Answer (score 0):

Before Java 1.5 there was only System.currentTimeMillis. However the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be large. On Windows XP I sometimes ended up with gaps of 20ms. I heard Linux is way better with gaps in the range of 1-2ms.

With Java 1.5 you can also use System.nanoTime. I never had problems with this one.

Answer (score -1):

One gotcha is that this measures real time elapsed, not CPU time - so it is very dependent on system load. This is fine if your on an otherwise free machine, but can sometimes produce interesting results if other processes are trying to do work.

[This article](http://tanso.net/java_cputime.html) has an intersting solution to the problem.

Comment: Downvoted because referenced link is not available anymore. Please quote the relevant informaiton.