# Measuring time in Java

Tags: java, performance, time, profiling

So I was trying to measure the time two different algorithm implementations took to accomplish a given task, and here is the result:

```
i    alg1  alg2
4   0.002   0.0
5   0.001   0.0
6   0.003   0.002
7   0.023   0.01
8   0.055   0.041
9   0.056   0.0
10  0.208   0.101
11  1.767   0.694
12  18.581  7.784
```

being `i` just some input parameter.

I've measured the performance of the algorithms making use of the following (naive) function:

```
private double getDuration() {
    return (double)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / (double)1000;
}
```

What would be the preferable way of getting more real results (other than 0.0, which obviously isn't true!) than using `System.currentTimeMillis()`? I know I could just run the algorithms over and over again and sum their results, but I have this gut feeling that there is probably some more robust way of measuring passed time in Java (both `real`, `user` and `sys`, if possible!).

Thanks

Comment: When you measure very short intervals you end up measuring the measuring logic more than you measure your intended "target".

Comment: and what's the problem with running each alg million times? with random params?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For basic timing, you can use Guava's [`Stopwatch` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) (or just grab its source code if you don't want to pull in the whole Guava library). For a more complete benchmarking solution look at [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) by the same team.

Both of these are based on `System.nanoTime()`, which you should prefer over `System.currentTimeMillis()` for measuring elapsed time. The basic reason why is that `System.currentTimeMillis()` is a "clock" (which tries to return wall-time) whereas `System.nanoTime()` is a "timer" (which tries to return time since some arbitrary point).

You want a clock when you're trying to figure out when a single event happened, so you can line it up with your watch or the clock on your wall (or the clock in some other computer). But it's not appropriate for measuring the elapsed time between two events on the same system, since the computer will occasionally adjust its notion of how its own internal clock corresponds to wall-time. For instance, if you do

```
long timeA = System.currentTimeMillis();
doStuff();
long timeB = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (timeB - timeA));
```

it's possible to get a negative result if NTP adjusts backwards while `doStuff()` is executing. `System.nanoTime()`, being a timer instead of a clock, should ignore that adjustment thus avoid this problem.

(Note that all of the above is conceptual; unfortunately things can get messy at the implementation level. But this doesn't change the recommendation: `System.nanoTime()` is supposed to be the best timer you can get on your platform, and `System.currentMilliseconds()` is supposed to be the best clock you can get.)

Comment: Important note: for benchmarking like the OP is describing, the Guava team recommends the use of [Caliper](http://caliper.googlecode.com).

Answer (score 2):

`System.nanoTime();` perhaps, is what you're looking for. And add calculations for standard deviation and average time.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider running your algorithms many times and averaging the result.

There are three reasons for this:

1. It makes timing easier, for the reasons you have identified.
2. The JVM "warms up" and the performance of your code will change as it does: The hotspot JVM won't compile fully until you've run a method a large number of times. If you don't get past this your results won't be representative.
3. It's always a good idea to average out the times, to avoid spurious effects due to external events like GC, or other stuff running on your computer.

As a rule of thumb, try running your algos 10,000 times as a warm up, then 10,000 times afterwards. Modify the numbers to suit your runtimes...

[Here's an article](http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/microbench.htm) explaining the same thing.

Comment: Nice answer. One more thing, when the only thing I want is to *compare* both algorithms, wouldn't I be better running the JVM with the -Xint flag on so that I don't have to worry about weird JIT effects?

Comment: Surely you're interested in comparing the performance of your algos under normal operation, which includes compilation? In which case absolutely not - the interpreted runtimes are probably irrelevant. Presumably you're comparing them because the performance matters to you when used in some larger app? If you don't run the tests in a realistic environment then the results themselves won't be realistic.

Answer (score 1):

You could instrument the code and count the number of bytecodes executed. You can do this with [bycounter](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/ByCounter).

This may not be ideal for your purposes. If the programs differ by only a very few bytecodes  it may not give an accurate measure of which program is actually more performant, as the cost of executing bytecodes can vary wildly. Also, if there is network or disk reads during your program, the bytecode count could give the wrong comparison.