# LFU cache - Random/Inconsistent results

Tags: caching, concurrency

I have the following implementation of an LFU - least frequently used - cache. In case there is a tie between elements which have the same use count then the timestamp is used as a tie breaker to evict the least recently used element

```java
public class LFUCache {

    class CacheKey {
        private int counter;
        private long timestamp;
        private int value;

        public CacheKey(int counter, long timestamp, int value) {
            this.counter = counter;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.value = value;
        }

        long getTimestamp() {
            return this.timestamp;
        }

        int getCounter() {
            return this.counter;
        }

        void incrementCounter() {
            this.counter++;
        }

        void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            CacheKey other = (CacheKey) o;
            return other.counter == this.counter && other.timestamp == this.timestamp && this.value == other.value;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.counter, this.timestamp, this.value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CacheKey{" +
                    "counter=" + counter +
                    ", timestamp=" + timestamp +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Map from cache key to its corresponding key
     */
    TreeMap<CacheKey, Integer> timeKeeper;

    /**
     * Map from keys to the keys of th timekeeper map
     */
    Map<Integer, CacheKey> cache;

    /**
     * Total capacity of the cache
     */
    int capacity;

    /**
     * Compare first on the least frequently used, so we are keeping the elements of the cache with the smallest
     * counters in the first entries of the tree map.
     * <p>
     * In case of a tie we have to evict the least recently used, so we are using the timestamp entry, and we are keeping
     * the ones with the smaller
     */
    public LFUCache(int capacity) {

        this.timeKeeper = new TreeMap(Comparator.comparingInt(CacheKey::getCounter).thenComparingLong(CacheKey::getTimestamp));
        this.cache = new HashMap();
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if (this.cache.containsKey(key)) {
            CacheKey searchKey = this.cache.get(key);

            // We have to remove the old entry from the timekeeper map and re add it to the tree map
            // since if we update only the reference the sorting will not take place again
            this.timeKeeper.remove(searchKey);

            // Update the entry in the timekeeper map with an updated counter and a new last used timestamp
            searchKey.incrementCounter();
            searchKey.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.timeKeeper.put(searchKey, key);
            return this.cache.get(key).value;
        } else return -1;
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        // Check if we have to remove something from the map
        if (this.cache.size() == this.capacity) {

            // Remove the least frequently used OR - in case of a tie - least recently used element
            Map.Entry<CacheKey, Integer> lfuEntry = this.timeKeeper.pollFirstEntry();
            CacheKey lfuKey = lfuEntry.getKey();
            Integer lfuValue = lfuEntry.getValue();

            // Remove elements from both cache and timekeeper
            this.timeKeeper.remove(lfuKey);
            this.cache.remove(lfuValue);
        }

        // Check if it is present
        if (this.cache.containsKey(key)) {
            CacheKey searchKey = this.cache.get(key);

            // Remove the old entry from the timekeeper map. Again here we remove the old entry from the timekeeper map
            // and re add it to the tree map since if we update only the reference the sorting will not take place
            this.timeKeeper.remove(searchKey);

            // Update the entry in the timekeeper map with an updated counter and a new last used timestamp
            searchKey.incrementCounter();
            searchKey.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            searchKey.setValue(value);

            this.timeKeeper.put(searchKey, key);
            this.cache.put(key, searchKey);

        } else {
            // Now add the new element
            doPut(key, value);
        }
    }

    private void doPut(int key, int value) {
        CacheKey cacheKey = new CacheKey(1, System.currentTimeMillis(), value);
        this.timeKeeper.put(cacheKey, key);
        this.cache.put(key, cacheKey);
    }
}
```

I have the following test to verify that everything is working as expected

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            LFUCache lfuCache = new LFUCache(2);
            lfuCache.put(1, 1);
            lfuCache.put(2, 2);
            System.out.println(lfuCache.get(1));
            lfuCache.put(3, 3);
            System.out.println(lfuCache.get(2));
            System.out.println(lfuCache.get(3));
            lfuCache.put(4, 4);
            System.out.println(lfuCache.get(1));
            System.out.println(lfuCache.get(3));
            System.out.println(lfuCache.get(4));

    }
```

The results I am getting are random. I would expect to get

```
1
-1
3
-1
3
4
```

and I do get this sometimes but I also get

```
1
2
3
-1
3
4
```

or

```
1
-1
3
-1
3
4
```

and all sorts of other results. I tried to create synchronized methods

```java
public synchronized int get(int key) {...}
public synchronized void put(int key, int value) {...}
```

and I still get random results
I tried to synchronize blocks inside methods e.g.

```java
    public int get(int key) {
        if (this.cache.containsKey(key)) {
            synchronized(this){
                CacheKey searchKey = this.cache.get(key);

                // Remove the old entry from the timekeeper map
                this.timeKeeper.remove(searchKey);

                // Create a new entry in the timekeeper map with an updated counter and a new last used timestamp
                CacheKey updatedKey = new CacheKey(searchKey.getCounter() + 1, System.currentTimeMillis(), searchKey.value);
                this.timeKeeper.put(updatedKey, key);
                return this.cache.get(key).value;
            }
            
        } else return -1;
    }
```

I still get random results

I tried to synchronized on the `timeKeeper` and `cache` objects e.g.

```java
    public int get(int key) {
        if (this.cache.containsKey(key)) {
            synchronized(this.timeKeeper){
                synchronized(this.cache){
                    CacheKey searchKey = this.cache.get(key);

                    // Remove the old entry from the timekeeper map
                    this.timeKeeper.remove(searchKey);

                    // Create a new entry in the timekeeper map with an updated counter and a new last used timestamp
                    CacheKey updatedKey = new CacheKey(searchKey.getCounter() + 1, System.currentTimeMillis(), searchKey.value);
                    this.timeKeeper.put(updatedKey, key);
                    return this.cache.get(key).value;
                }
            }
        } else return -1;
    }
```

but I still get random results

I also tried to use a SyncronizedMap instead of a HashMap but I still get random results.

I cannot really use `Collections.synchronizedMap(TreeMap)` because this will yield a Map and I cannot use the TreeMap API on it.

So what other options do I have here?

This is a single threaded environment. It's just a main method. How can I have random results being produced?

Comment: Your test in `main()` is single-threaded, so there is no concurrency and the flaw is likely in the implementation itself. In which case synchronization does not help. Please also analyse more use cases. For example, your code assumes that every key you use in `get(key,value)` exists, because if it doesn't, you'll get a `NullPointerException` in `CacheKey updatedKey = new CacheKey(searchKey.getCounter() + 1,  ....` because `searchKey` is `null`.

Comment: Hello @Emmef. Thanks for your response. This assumption is made because the keys in both maps are updated together - that is why I never get a `NullPointerException`. I put the test in a loop and iterated a million times. How can it not a be a concurrency issue if the results are different every time (?)

Comment: your code does not start any threads, so you have only one thread. Therefore, no other thread can _concurrently_ access your code, as there is no such thread. I admit that I did miss the outer `this.cache.containsKey(key))` though ;-)  
If you use synchronisation, you must also include this outer check. Because the key can be removed by another thread before your thread enters the synchronised block, and in _that_ case, you _will_ get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I understand the single threaded nature of this implementation but I cannot come up with a better idea for the random results than the concurrency idea.

Comment: Since you are using `System.currentTimeMillis()` there is a chance of ties only in some runs, as that part of the execution is non-deterministic. Instead maintain your own clock that advances on every call to stabilize your tests.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Inpired by @BenManes comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243059/lfu-cache-random-inconsistent-results?noredirect=1#comment122390519_69243059) I starting thinking whether `System.currentTimeMillis()` was the best way to go and I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073325/is-system-currenttimemillis-the-best-measure-of-time-performance-in-java). I replaced `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `System.nanoTime()`. Now not only do I have consistent results but I have the **right** results.

Comment: You might enjoy reading over this [alternative](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/linked/FrequentlyUsedPolicy.java) strategy for an LFU, which is O(1) time complexity and does not use the system's time.